# can't find libcrypto.so to build the library via android-ndk in cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk

I have to build library  for my android application which uses native java libraries. When I run the commend `(ndk-folder)/ndk-build` it gives an error like

`haredLibrary  : libSimpleService.so
/opt/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../../lib/libcrypto.a when searching for -lcrypto
/opt/android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/opt/alljoyn-sdk-2-0-0/alljoyn_2_0_0_rel/samples/simple/service/obj/local/armeabi/libSimpleService.so]`

I guess the reason is due to fact that I should use "libcrypto.so", because it is an Alljoyn project actually. but i cannot find it. I tried adb pull it from my phone (Huawei ideox x5) but it says "device not found" whenever i try it (i havent rooted the phone yet), and i cant see the file in the phone either.
Anybody who has a solution??
Cheers,
Fena

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn also need libssl.so which are both located at /system/lib/.

So you have to use a rooted moblie phone.

Answer (score -1):

This is best link for learning Android NDK projects 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

i hope you got a solution for this